# Get reference to Root element in custom element using svelte

Tags: custom-controls, svelte

When debugging svelte component compiled as a custom control I can see in the compiled code `function instance($$self, $$props, $$invalidate)` where $$self is the actual "root" element of the component.

Trying to get this `$$self` in the code leads to an compile time error..

What should I do to get the reference to the shadowRootNode in Svelte, I need it when I want to dispatch a custom event from my custom control e.g 'PersonPicked'

Comment: This isn't currently possible — it would be worth opening an issue on https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues to discuss how we could solve it